# opencart payment extension callback not working

Tags: php, opencart

im trying to build a custom payment module. I have 80% completed it. But im having a few issues with it.

In the callback, when the user is returned to the site if a payment is successful or failed. It shows me as

> The page you requested cannot be found! The page you requested cannot
>   be found.

when i try to directly access the callback page it gives me a blank page.

```
index.php?route=payment/hyperion/callback
```

and when a payment is successful and returned to my page (which gives me the page cannot be found). i dont see the order in the "Orders" page. It doesn't update if the payment is successful

below is my callback function

```
           public function callback() {

    $this->load->model('checkout/order');

    $order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);

    $order_id = $order_info['order_id'];

    if ($order_info) {
        $this->language->load('payment/hyper');

        $this->data['title'] = sprintf($this->language->get('heading_title'), $this->config->get('config_name'));

        if (!isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] != 'on')) {
            $this->data['base'] = HTTP_SERVER;
        } else {
            $this->data['base'] = HTTPS_SERVER;
        }

        $this->data['language'] = $this->language->get('code');
        $this->data['direction'] = $this->language->get('direction');

        $this->data['heading_title'] = sprintf($this->language->get('heading_title'), $this->config->get('config_name'));

        $this->data['text_response'] = $this->language->get('text_response');
        $this->data['text_success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
        $this->data['text_success_wait'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success_wait'), $this->url->link('checkout/success'));
        $this->data['text_failure'] = $this->language->get('text_failure');
        $this->data['text_failure_wait'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_failure_wait'), $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));

        if (isset($_POST['flag_msg']) && $_POST['flag_msg'] == 'Status_Success') {
            $this->load->model('checkout/order');

            $this->model_checkout_order->confirm($order_id, $this->config->get('config_order_status_id'));

            $message = '';

            if (isset($_POST['flag_msg'])) {
                $message .= 'Payment Status = ' . $_POST['flag_msg'] . "\n";
                }

                if (isset($_POST['Response'])) {
                $message .= 'Response = ' . $_POST['Response'] . "\n";
                }

                if (isset($_POST['Result'])) {
                $message .= 'Result= ' . $_POST['Result'] . "\n";

                }

            $this->model_checkout_order->update($order_id, $this->config->get('hyper_order_status_id'), $message, false);

            $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('checkout/success');

            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/hyper_success.tpl')) {
                $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/hyper_success.tpl';
            } else {
                $this->template = 'default/template/payment/hyper_success.tpl';
            }

            $this->children = array(  
                'common/column_left',
                'common/column_right',
                'common/content_top',
                'common/content_bottom',
                'common/footer',
                'common/header'
            );

            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
        }
        else if (isset($_POST['flag_msg']) && $_POST['flag_msg'] == 'Status_Fail') {
            $this->load->model('checkout/order');

            $this->model_checkout_order->confirm($order_id, $this->config->get('config_order_status_id'));

            $message = '';

            if (isset($_POST['flag_msg'])) {
                $message .= 'Payment Status = ' . $_POST['flag_msg'] . "\n";
                }

                if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
                $message .= 'Reason= ' . $_POST['message'] . "\n";
                }


            $this->model_checkout_order->update($order_id, 'Failed', $message, false);

            $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout');

            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/hyper_failure.tpl')) {
                $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/hyper_failure.tpl';
            } else {
                $this->template = 'default/template/payment/hyper_failure.tpl';
            }

            $this->children = array(
                'common/column_left',
                'common/column_right',
                'common/content_top',
                'common/content_bottom',
                'common/footer',
                'common/header'
            );

            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
        } else {
            $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');

            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/hyper_failure.tpl')) {
                $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/hyper_failure.tpl';
            } else {
                $this->template = 'default/template/payment/hyper_failure.tpl';
            }

            $this->children = array(
                'common/column_left',
                'common/column_right',
                'common/content_top',
                'common/content_bottom',
                'common/footer',
                'common/header'
            );

            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
        }
    }
}
```

can someone help me on this?

Comment: What about turning on `display_errors` or `error_log` and then checking what is wrong there? Though You provided the whole callback code, it is too much lines to check one by one to find out that You are missing ending brace or semicolon somewhere... This should be checked even before posting question here... If You did, then You should mention that there is no error but the blank page (which indicates there is an error but display errors is set to false)...

Comment: @shadyyx i have turned on error_display, but there is no error. I dont see any error in the error logs. there is no syntax error so far. but i still get the blank page, no errors when accessed directly..

Comment: And are You sure You have allowed reporting of all kind of errors (including notices, warnings, deprecated, etc.) ?

Comment: And did You try some simple debugging to make sure that the action is really executed? Like `echo "Yes, I am here";` right after the `callback` function opening bracket?

Answer (score 1):

For **OpenCart version 2.3** a valid url for callback is

```
index.php?route=extension/payment/my_controller/callback
```

because internal opencartv2.3 structure has next form: my_site/catalog/controller/**extension/payment/my_controller**.php

For default success and fail (but opencart mean fail as return to checkout process) actions there are standard links:

```
index.php?route=checkout/success
index.php?route=checkout/checkout
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to get the order info with an order_id from the session and not from the data that you got back, there seems to lie the problem also from my point of view as the only possibility that your code will return a blank page from logical point of view is if not order info are specified, and the case that this may happen is if there is a problem with the order id from the session you try to get.

Other than that nothing else seemed wrong with your code.

My advice if there is a order id returned, i do  not think any payment method does not return one, try and use that order id and see how things go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some things to debug.
* You can put echo 'hello' or var_dump('hello') inside your function to see if your function is even getting called and executed. 
* If it is then you should put the echo/var_dump after every line to see where the code stopped.

Further, the url passed to the payment for callback needs to be 
$this->url->link('payment/{module_name}/callback', '', 'SSL');
supposing your file directory is in catalog/controller/payment.

This is for opencart version 2.1.x and less. For above you can easily change the url checking the directory structure.

NOTE: One more thing that could happen is the order id you are getting in your session is not there when the function gets executed. Do the var_dump debug method to see in which line the code stopped working.